# (Labeled, if possible) time-series datasets for anomaly detection

Tags: time-series, dataset, anomaly-detection, labels, labelling

I would like to create a big list of available time-series datasets for anomaly detection. I'm especially interested in the following:

- The time-series data should be segmented into cycles
- Ideally, these cycles should be of the same length
- These cycles should be labeled as normal/anomalous

But anything goes. I will be sharing the ones I found below.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I want to post it on open data

Comment: Please link to the Open Data question if you do put it there

Answer (score 1):

- [Kaggle's NAB](https://www.kaggle.com/boltzmannbrain/nab): a variety of sources such as AWS server metrics, Twitter volume, advertisement clicking metrics, traffic data, and more. Data is labeled.
- [Kaggle's Wafer](https://www.kaggle.com/arbazkhan971/anomaly-detection): manufacturing data, 2K datapoints, 143 labeled anomalies. Measures are taken every 10 milliseconds.